# jquery change tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I have this code that doesn't work, can you help me? I want that I changed tag name "p" of class="s7" to "h1"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".s7").replaceWith($('<h1>' + $(this).html() + '</h1>');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What happens in your example? And won't `this` be your document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're matching all the elements with class `s7`, but you need to process them one by one in order to copy their content into new elements. In your current code, `this` is always `document`, not the current element.

You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the matched elements:

```
$(".s7").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.replaceWith($("<h1>" + $this.html() + "</h1>"));
});
```

Or maybe:

```
$(".s7").each(function() {
    $("<h1>" + $(this).html() + "</h1>").replaceAll(this);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a closing parenthesis, and you're using *this* in the wrong context:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".s7").replaceWith($('<h1>' + $(".s7").html() + '</h1>'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L82PW/

If you have multiple elements with a class name of `s7`, use `.each()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".s7").each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($('<h1>' + $(this).html() + '</h1>'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` in your "replaceWith()" call is not going to be the "s7" element; it's going to be whatever `this` is in the greater "document.ready" handler.

To do what you want, use ".each()":

```
  $('.s7').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<h1>' + $(this).html() + '</h1>'));
  });
```

With that version, jQuery will call the "each" function for each element with class "s7".  Inside that function call, furthermore, jQuery arranges for `this` to refer to one of those DOM elements on each iteration.

To further elaborate the difference, consider that in both my version and yours the argument to "replaceWith()" is computed **before** ".replaceWith()" is called.  That is, the string concatenation expression involving `$(this)` is evaluated before the function call.  Thus, there's just no way for `this` to take on the value of any element in the chain; JavaScript simply does not work that way.

With the ".each()" loop, however, we can ensure that `this` has a useful value.  Note that ".each()" *also* passes a reference to the current DOM element as an explicit parameter, so the code could also look like:

```
  $('.s').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).replaceWith($('<h1>' + $(element).html() + '</h1>'));
  });
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end there.

Comment: oops yes I just saw your answer and was checking mine :-)   Thanks!