# jQuery html5 tag change to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the `<footer id="tt"></footer>` to `<div id='tt'></div>` use jQuery
Is there a way to change the tag easily? 
Many thanks

Comment: By doing a simple search on google, I get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380137/jquery-change-tag

Comment: btw, it is possible to change tag of jquery object, for example if we need to change tag of DOM object that received with $(selector).clone(true), or just better to clone all it's children to new object ? what if need to handle same events  as original object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replaceWith` method:

```
$('#tt').replaceWith(function(){
   return '<div id="' + this.id + '"></div>'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceWith()`

```
var $foot=$('#tt'), html=$foot.html();

$foot.replaceWith( $('<div id="tt">').append(html) )
```